# Personalization of superset mapbox tooltips

Tags: javascript, mapbox, apache-superset

According to superset pull request it's possible to personalize the tooltip for geographic data using some JavaScript.

[image]

I've tried many things to get my point data to the tooltip, yet none of them work.

Where does Superset store the extra JS parameters?

The `object.props.OwnData` referenced in this PR does not work https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/4173

I've no idea where my extra parameters go into the JavaScript environment.

Comment: in my environment, this function is disabled. How to enable it. Please share. Thanks.

Comment: add ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_CONTROLS = True in you superset config file ;)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried add ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_CONTROLS = True and restart superset, but still function disable. Wondering why.

Comment: I had to enable it directly in superset/config.py in order for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

`` d => `test: ${d.object.extraProps.occupancy}` ``
works for me

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score -1):

To enable java script on superset - you need to change admin roles-- add 'can embed on dashboard' then it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).