# JavaScript tooltip generator in Apache Superset is not showing the data

Tags: javascript, apache-superset

I am new to Apache superset and I am trying to add a JavaScript tooltip to a geo map visualization.

I am using this piece of code in the "JavaScript tooltip generator":

`d => "<div>field: <strong> ${d.object.props.ColumnName_Test} </strong></div>"`

[image]

The value of the column name is not visible on the tooltip, but the hardcoded column name is visible:
[image]

I have googled a lot, but there is no documentation about how to use the JavaScript tooltip generator in Apache Superset.

Does someone know what I need to change in this piece of code to show the value of the column, instead of the column name?

Answer (score 1):

Did you first add `ColumnName_Test` variable to the "Extra data for JS"?

Check also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60040471/personalization-of-superset-mapbox-tooltips/62181562#62181562)

[image]