# Superset Graph chart rollover/tooltip

Tags: javascript, apache-superset

I'm new to Superset and am trying to amend the information displayed on tooltip/mouse rollover of a node when using the Graph Chart (the network chart viz).

Any ideas?  What/where is the javascript tooltip generator?

Tried using the default settings and tried info found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401803/javascript-tooltip-generator-in-apache-superset-is-not-showing-the-data)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript tooltip generator is only used by the DeckGL plugins, and is also turned off by default in Superset's configuration anyway, since it's an inroad to XSS exploits. I believe to customize these tooltips for the Graph Chart, you/we would need to modify the plugin and add extra controls to the control panel. Feel free to join us on the `#customizing-superset` channel in the Superset community [Slack workspace](https://join.slack.com/t/apache-superset/shared_invite/zt-1jp6hjzrq-H0PlFtToyLWuPiJDuRWCNw) if you'd like to have a discussion about how to get involved designing/building this feature.